# How to convert a Base64 encoded string to UUID format

Tags: ruby, hex, base64, uuid

How can I convert a Base64 encoded string to a hex encoded string with dashes(basically to uuid format)?

For example if I have

```
'FWLalpF2T5mmyxS03Q+hNQ0K'
```

then how can I convert it to:

```
1562da96-9176-4f99-a6cb-14b4dd0fa135
```

Comment: Can be done with [`String#unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-unpack) (`m` for Base64 and `H` for hex string) + [`Array#join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join) to add `-`.

Comment: But how do I split the string as per uuid pattern?

Comment: `Each directive may be followed by a number, indicating the number of times to repeat with this directive.` E.g. `"H8H4`" to unpack the base64 *de*coded string to `["1562da96", "9167"]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was familiar with `unpack` but this prompted me to learn the directive as pointed out by cremno.

simplest form:

```
b64 = 'FWLalpF2T5mmyxS03Q+hNQ0K'
b64.unpack("m0").first.unpack("H8H4H4H4H12").join('-')

#=> "1562da96-9176-4f99-a6cb-14b4dd0fa135"

b64.unpack("m0")
```

give us:

```
#=> ["\x15b\xDA\x96\x91vO\x99\xA6\xCB\x14\xB4\xDD\x0F\xA15\r\n"]
```

which is an array so we use `.first` to grab the string and unpack again using the directive to format it in the 8-4-4-4-12 format:

```
b64.unpack("m0").first.unpack("H8H4H4H4H12")
```

gives us:

```
#=> ["1562da96", "9176", "4f99", "a6cb", "14b4dd0fa135"]
```

an array of strings, so now we just join it with the `-`:

```
b64.unpack("m0").first.unpack("H8H4H4H4H12").join('-')

#=> "1562da96-9176-4f99-a6cb-14b4dd0fa135"
```

Comment: Converting the (base64) string to  UUID should IMO shouldn't produce identical UUID for different strings, however, this solution does. Let's alter the last character in the string from K to L:

`'FWLalpF2T5mmyxS03Q+hNQ0K'.unpack("H8H4H4H4H12").join('-') == 'FWLalpF2T5mmyxS03Q+hNQ0L'.unpack("H8H4H4H4H12").join('-')
# => true`

Answer (score 3):

**OOPS**

The accepted answer has a flaw:

```
b64 = 'FWLalpF2T5mmyxS03Q+hNQ0K'
b64.unpack("m0").first.unpack("H8H4H4H4H12").join('-')
# => "1562da96-9176-4f99-a6cb-14b4dd0fa135"
```

Changing the last char in the b64 string results in the same UUID:

```
b64 = 'FWLalpF2T5mmyxS03Q+hNQ0L'
b64.unpack("m0").first.unpack("H8H4H4H4H12").join('-')
# => "1562da96-9176-4f99-a6cb-14b4dd0fa135"
```

To prevent this, you might want to hash your input (base64 or anything else) to the correct length e.g. with MD5:

```
require "digest"
b64 = 'FWLalpF2T5mmyxS03Q+hNQ0K'
Digest::MD5.hexdigest(b64).unpack("a8a4a4a4a12").join('-')
# => "df71c785-6552-a977-e0ac-8edb8fd63f6f"
```

Now the full input is relevant, altering the last char results in a different UUID:

```
require "digest"
b64 = 'FWLalpF2T5mmyxS03Q+hNQ0L'
Digest::MD5.hexdigest(s).unpack("a8a4a4a4a12").join('-')
# => "2625f170-d05a-f65d-38ff-5d9a7a972382"
```